# How to post altered form values upon submit with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, post

This seems like a silly question, but recently I've been more and more in need of a quite common feature, that I can't find anywhere: I need to do some manipulation with the form data before sending it, but I don't want to show this to the user - I don't want to set the text of the field on the screen, but rather access the place where the values are stored and change one of them right before submit. Normally I'd leave the text field without name, and create a hidden field that would be sent. Upon submit, I copy the text of the nameless field, using it's id, parse it, and then set that to the hidden field, that is finally post. But that seems quite a bit of effort to do something so simple. There are plenty of reasons why one would do such a thing: remove masks, encrypt a password, change a date from local native format to database... All this things can be done server side, of course, but most of them would be way better client side: you'd need to send less data over network, it'd greatly simplify posterior server-side validation... Anyway, is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: All the examples you gave are much better done server side. The data you send over the network will be more-or-less the same for all of them, and it would complicate server side validation because you would have to reverse them to pre-populate the form if validation failed. Encryption in transit should be done via SSL (which is transparent to the client side and server side code).

Comment: Agreed with Quentin. You can rely on the server side, not so much the client side.

Comment: You can use a submit handler, potentially with an ajax-submit, but none of your examples need this.  The one that comes closest is the local date format, however, that is best solved by storing an ISO-formatted date in your form-field and using a "widget" to translate from what the user enters.